# relative transformation over a hierarchy of ui elements

Tags: c++, user-interface, unreal-engine4

I'm programming a lightweight ui system in c++ (for unreal engine 4). I have the ui element base class, that can add children ui elements. The problem I am facing now is with my layout manager. I need all elements to relarively move, size and rotate with the parent ui element.

An element should be able to rotate around its local pivot, but still rotate with its parent. Thus I need the layout manager class to iterate over all ui elements in a hierarchy and calculate these positions sizes and rotational values.

Its just that I can't really figure out an algorithm for how to transform the child elements relative to its parent.

For each element, these variables are known: position, size, rotation (quaternion), and pivot position. These are 2D vectors except for rotation which is "float".

As I want to retain the values as they were before layout calculations, I want these calculated values stored in seperate variables.

Any help on this would be god send!

Best regards,
Oyvind

Comment: `... I want to retain the [original] values...` does this mean that you want a full history of where everything has been over many movements, or just where it is now and where it will be/has been over the course of a single movement?

Comment: I want the values that were initially set, and internal values for what the layoutmanager calculates. So an element should have a "width" property, and a "actual width" property. The actual width would then be what the layoutmanager calculates, taking margins and padding of elements into account forexample.